# In Python, taking the string out of b'...' how can I convert that string back to bytes?

Tags: python

Say, I've a byte string, e.g.:

```py
bs: bytes = b'\xaf]\x95Q\x0b'
```

Now, take out the string part by copy and paste and assign it to a string variable:

```py
s: string = "\xaf]\x95Q\x0b"
```

How do I convert `s`, say with a function `cnv(s: str) -> bytes`, back to bytes so the expression `bs == cnv(s)` evaluates to `True`?

Comment: [`bs.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) and [`s.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).

Comment: @OlvinRoght please post it as an answer, don't asnwer in comments

Comment: @FlyingTeller, it doesn't deserve to be an answer as this question is obviously a duplicate and will be closed soon.

Comment: _"take out the string part by copy and paste and assign it to a string variable"_ - why?

Comment: @jonsharpe, this was the shortest way to set up the question. Explaining why would need to describe the whole situation which would run counter to the rules of SO for asking questions: "keep it consise".

Comment: As far as I can tell the only place "concise" appears in the [help] is in https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits. [Ask] suggests you _"Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve"_, which helps avoid [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: @jonsharpe, If you insist. A customer uses these to communicate bytes over a serial line. C'est tout.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, I surmised that much. But it was beyond me which codec to use. So, your answer wasn't that useful to me. Because I couldn't find the appropriate codec, I was under the impression that some other _pythonic_ way would exists, and therefore I decided to post the question.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question, [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) must still be a question and answer pair. If you edit the question to clarify where it departs from the current dupe ("Edit:" isn't needed, we can all see the history) it can be reviewed for reopening. How you _actually get `s`_ is useful context to include.